# How to define a function in ghci across multiple lines?

Tags: haskell, ghci, multiline-repl-definition

I'm trying to define any simple function that spans multiple lines in ghci, take the following as an example:

```
let abs n | n >= 0 = n
          | otherwise = -n
```

So far I've tried pressing Enter after the first line:

```
Prelude> let abs n | n >= 0 = n
Prelude>           | otherwise = -n
<interactive>:1:0: parse error on input `|'
```

I've also attempted to use the `:{` and `:}` commands but I don't get far:

```
Prelude> :{
unknown command ':{'
use :? for help.
```

I'm using GHC Interactive version 6.6 for Haskell 98 on Linux, what am I missing?

Comment: Please upgrade your GHC installation. GHC 6.6 is nearly 5 years old! The latest versions of Haskell are here: http://haskell.org/platform

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-line commands in GHCi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443035/multi-line-commands-in-ghci)

Comment: @Mark This OP already tried the solutions to that problem. This problem is due to an out-of-date ghci, not lack of knowledge of what to do. Solution here: upgrade. Solution there: use `:{`, `:}`.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

For guards (like your example), you can just put them all on one line and it works (guards do not care about spacing)

```
let abs n | n >= 0 = n | otherwise = -n
```

If you wanted to write your function with multiple definitions that pattern match on the arguments, like this:

```
fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * fact (n-1)
```

Then you would use braces with semicolons separating the definitions

```
let { fact 0 = 1 ; fact n = n * fact (n-1) }
```

Answer (score 298):

GHCi now has a multiline-input mode, enabled with :set +m. For example,

```
Prelude> :set +m
Prelude> let fac 0 = 1
Prelude|     fac n = n * fac (n-1)
Prelude|
Prelude> fac 10
3628800
```

Comment: Setting multiline mode makes `ghci` behave much like the Python interpreter in this regard. Very convenient! You can in fact create a `.ghci` file in your home directory in which you put `:set +m` and multiline mode will become the default every time you start `ghci`!

Comment: This is really awesome. But I have noticed that when I set my prompt using `:set prompt "λ "` the continued lines say `Prelude` instead of `λ`. Any way to get around this?

Comment: See here for the patch to define a new continuation prompt https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7509#no1

Comment: To prevent Prelude appearing on continuation lines, also add :set prompt2 "| " in your .ghci.

Comment: You can *completely* avoid indentation using a trailing `let`.

Simply type a `let` followed by a newline: `let` ⏎.

Then `fac 0 = 1` ⏎.

Then `fac n = n * fac (n-1)` ⏎ ⏎ and you're done!

Comment: `:set prompt2 "| "` now seems to be `:set prompt-cont "| "`. Not sure when the change was made, but I'm using GHC 8.6.3.

Comment: I believe @Iceland_jack’s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines#comment66413573_19798581) makes this an excellent answer, because 1) tab invokes auto-complete by default so indentation is not straight-forward; 2) `let` used in this way is really just a trick of convenience for ghci.

Answer (score 79):

Dan is correct, but `:{` and `:}` must each appear on their own line:

```
> :{ 
> let foo a b = a +
>           b
> :}
> :t foo
foo :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

This also interacts with the layout rule, so when using do-notation it might be easier to use braces and semi-colons explicitly. For example, this definition fails:

```
> :{
| let prRev = do
|   inp <- getLine
|   putStrLn $ reverse inp
| :}
<interactive>:1:18:
    The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression
```

But it works when braces and semi-colons are added:

```
> :{
| let prRev = do {
|   inp <- getLine;
|   putStrLn $ reverse inp;
| }
| :}
> :t prRev
prRev :: IO ()
```

This will only really matter when pasting definitions from a file, where indentation might change.

Comment: This doesn't work if you have a line ending in '=' (with the definition following on the next line), at least in version 7.6.3.

Comment: Perhaps this fails, because the second and third line of the let are not indented enough…? (Two more spaces.)

Comment: This is a great approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 23):

It looks like `:{` and `:}` are a pretty new feature. You may need to upgrade GHC.

Edit: confirmed, see http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.8.2/html/users_guide/release-6-8-2.html

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to upgrade GHC just for `:{` and `:}`, you'll need to write it all on one line:

```
> let abs' n | n >= 0 = n | otherwise = -n
```

I'm not aware of any single definition in Haskell that *must* be written on multiple lines. The above does indeed work in GHCi:

```
> :t abs'
abs' :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a
```

For other expressions, such as `do` blocks, you'll need to use the non-layout syntax with curly braces and semicolons (eugh).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like pasting both lines at once or using control-enter for each new line keeps it all together, at least at https://repl.it/languages/haskell.  You'll see 2 dots in the beginning of the second line.  Or put it in a file and :load the file (:l main).  How come abs doesn't work with negative numbers?  Oh you have to put parentheses around the number.

```
   let abs n | n >= 0 = n 
..           | otherwise = -n
```

```
   abs (-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using GHCi, version 8.2.1 on macOS Catalina 10.15.2. The following is how I put both function type declaration and guards together. Note the vertical bars on the left are for GHCi multiple lines.

```
λ: let abs' :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a
 |     abs' n | n >= 0 = n | otherwise = -n
 | 
λ: abs' 7
7
λ: abs' (-7)
7
```

Comment: If you use `:{` and `:}` you don't need to specify `let ` before your type declaration, meaning that you don't need to indent second and subsequent lines.

Comment: Thank you very much davidA. That's exactly what I had been looking for but failed to find.