# Haskell : "The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression"

Tags: haskell

I'm going through the book [Natural Language Processing for Working Programmers](http://nlpwp.org). The book uses Haskell, which I don't have much experience with. The code below throws an error in GHCI

```
:{
do
  l <- [0..9]
  ps <- (\x -> [x-1, x+2]) l
  return ps
:}
```

This is the error message returned

`The last statement in a 'do' construct must be an expression`

All answers I've come across seem to suggest it is an indentation error, but as far as I can tell the indentation seems correct. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: Which version of ghci are you using? On Windows/OSX/Ubuntu/Fedora/...?

Comment: 6.12.1 on Ubuntu 10.04. Might that be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typed your code into ghci 7.0.3 and did not get an error.

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| do
Prelude|   l <- [0..9]
Prelude|   ps <- (\x -> [x-1, x+2]) l
Prelude|   return ps
Prelude| :}
[-1,2,0,3,1,4,2,5,3,6,4,7,5,8,6,9,7,10,8,11]
```

**Edit:** When I use ghci 6.12.1 as packaged in Ubuntu 10.04, I get the same error as you.

Comment: I suspect I may have too old a version. I got it from the repos rather than the haskell website. 6.12.1 on Ubuntu 10.04. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that looks like the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The symbols of `:{` and `:}` are not part of Haskell, I think that is something to do with the text you are reading.  Also, the code you posted has a lambda being used as a list monad.  Try this:

```
do
  l <- [0..9]
  ps <- (\x -> [x-1, x+2]) l
  return ps
```

Comment: I was under the impression the `:{` and `:}` were necessary for multiline code in GHCi. Left out the list argument by mistake, sorry. I haven't quite wrapped my head around monads though. Am I supposed to use your code as is in GHCi? Each line is being interpreted independently.

Comment: I think I may have found a way out, based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/3532505/420386. Using semi-colons seems to solve the problem, although it makes me feel a little dirty :) Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed you were in GHCi (and forgot about that syntax).