# function definition inside GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is it possible to write **multi-line** function definitions with type-signature inside **GHCi** (as you would write it in a source file)?

I've tried so far something like this:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let f :: Int -> Int;
Prelude| f i = i + 1
Prelude| :}

<interactive>:9:1: parse error on input ‘f’
```

but it didn't work... Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define a function in ghci across multiple lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines)

Comment: You probably need to indent the line it's complaining about.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Thank you for your link to the possible duplicate question. I've actually read it before, but I couldn't find a way from the answers there how I could add the **type-signature** to the multi-line function definition inside `:{ :}`, so I've opened new question, but well since it was simple stupid identation problem from me, we could close this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mind the indentation:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| let f :: Int -> Int
Prelude|     f i = i + 1
Prelude| :}
Prelude> :t f
f :: Int -> Int
Prelude> f 1
2
```