# Have some troubles in implementing Insertion Sort function in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, insertion-sort

I am beginner level of the Haskell Language and I was trying to implement Insertion Sort function in Haskell in ghci environment.

here's my code.

```
prelude> let insert x [] = x:[]

insert :: t1 -> [t] -> [t1]

prelude> let insert x (y:ys) = 
if x < y then x:y:ys else y : insert ys


insert :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
```

I tried

```
insert 1 []
```

the result was [1], It worked well.

and I tried

```
insert 1 ([2,3])
```

the result was [1,2,3], Still it works well.

(Actually, I don't know why I have to parse on second argument list.
 but if I try insert 1 [2,3], it doesn't work.)

it worked well until this. but when I tried

```
insert 4 ([1,2,3])
```

It happened like this.

```
[1,2,3*** Exception: <interactive>:165:5-61: Non-exhaustive patterns in function
```

I don't why it did happen like this.please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are overwriting your first function `let insert x [] = x:[]` with another one (in your next `let insert ...` - this happens because you use `let ...` inside GHCi)

Instead you should create *.hs* file and load this into *GHCi* instead.

So fire up your favorite editor and insert this:

```
module MyInsertSort where

insert :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> [a]
insert x []     = x:[]
insert x (y:ys) = if x < y then x:y:ys else y : insert x ys
```

save it (I did as `MyInsert.hs`), start `ghci` and load it into it:

```
λ> :l MyInsert.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling MyInsertSort     ( MyInsert.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: MyInsertSort.
λ> insert 4 ([1,2,3])
[1,2,3,4]

λ> insert 1 ([2,3])
[1,2,3]
```

now it should work :D

### remarks

you had a small error in your second line `insert ys` instead of  `insert x ys`

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
but Is there other way to implement function in ghci directly?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines

Comment: @hasufell why not - maybe the OP will like that - I usually don't recommend this because you will learn to hate this quite quickly (when you reentered the thing the 3rd time) and writing a quick file (or even using emacs/vim) is much faster and better to experiment in the long run - after all it will take some time for Princeps to finish his insert-sort

Comment: I agree, I also rather load files via ghci and benefit from the power of my editor (syntax highlighting, hlint support etc.).