# Defining function signature in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

Defining a function signature in Haskell's interpreter GHCi doesn't work. Copying an example from [this page](https://wiki.haskell.org/Function):

```
Prelude> square :: Int -> Int

<interactive>:60:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
Prelude> square x = x * x
```

How can I declare a function signature and then give function definition in Haskell interactively? also: why can't I simply evaluate the function and see its type (e.g. `Prelude> square`) once it has been defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a function in ghci across multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You **can** define a function signature in the `ghc` interactive shell. The problem however is that you **need to define functions in a single command**.

You can use a *semicolon* (`;`) to split between two parts:

```
Prelude> square :: Int -> Int; square x = x * x
```

Note that the same holds for a **function with multiple clauses**. If you write:

```
Prelude> is_empty [] = True
Prelude> is_empty (_:_) = False
```

You have actually **overwritten the previous `is_empty` function** with the second statement. If we then query with an empty list, we get:

```
Prelude> is_empty []
*** Exception: <interactive>:4:1-22: Non-exhaustive patterns in function is_empty
```

So `ghci` took the last definition as a single clause function definition.

Again you have to write it like:

```
Prelude> is_empty[] = True; is_empty (_:_) = False
```

Comment: thank you. quick final followup: if i define it on one line, why can't i evaluate it after? ``Prelude> square`` returns ``Parse error: module header, import declaration or top-level declaration expected.``

Comment: full trace: ``Prelude> square :: Int -> Int; square x = x * x
Prelude> square

<interactive>:70:1: error:
    • No instance for (Show (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of ‘print’
        (maybe you haven't applied a function to enough arguments?)
    • In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
Prelude> square;;

<interactive>:71:1: error:
    Parse error: module header, import declaration
    or top-level declaration expected.``

Comment: @jll: but why do you write two additional semi-colons? You can calculate a square like with for instance `square 3`. The reason why `square` errors is because it is a function, and Haskell - by default - can not show functions.

Comment: it's confusing to me because I can evaluate instances of other types like ``1`` so if functions are first class why can't i evaluate a function and haskell print its type? i expected something like ``square :: Int -> Int`` as output

Comment: @jll: you can inspect the type of an expression with `:t`, so `:t square`.

Answer (score 19):

Multi-line input needs to be wrapped in the `:{` and `:}` commands.

```
λ> :{
 > square :: Int -> Int
 > square x = x * x
 > :}
square :: Int -> Int
```

Answer (score 16):

Here are three ways:

```
>>> square :: Int -> Int; square = (^2)
>>> let square :: Int -> Int
...     square = (^2)
...
>>> :{
... square :: Int -> Int
... square = (^2)
... :}
```

The second one requires you to `:set +m`; I include this in my `~/.ghci` so that it is always on.

Comment: important caveat: there must be no trailing spaces after `let square :: Int -> Int` for the second option to work.