# Is there a way to extract strings by index in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to implement the Haskell equivalent of the Python:

```py
> "abcdef"[1:3]
'bcd'
```

In fact, I'll try using the Haskell language for the first time. I do not know how to handle strings(or text???)

substr :: Text -> Int -> Int -> Text
????
I try to use 'take' and 'drop', but I do not know the exact order and function combination.

```hs
substr "abcdef" 1 3
“bcd”
```

Comment: Show us what you tried with `take` and `drop`, and explain why you don't like the result.

Comment: Can you show your attempt and what trouble(s) you have?

Comment: The difference between a `String` and `Text` is, roughly speaking, the fact that a `String` is a linked list of `Char`s (so `[Char]`), whereas a `Text` is a packed equivalent (so more an "array" of `Char`s).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Haskell's "built in" string type is called `String`, and it's actually just a list of `Char`.  In fact, if you try entering a list of `Char` at the GHCi prompt, it'll print it back to you in its `String` syntax:

```
> ['a','b','c']
"abc"
```

For "real" code, `String` is usually a terrible choice because it has all the performance you'd expect from a linked list of characters.  But, it's good enough for experimenting when you're learning Haskell.  You can learn about alternatives like `Text` later.

Because `String` is a list of char, `take` and `drop` work on it just like they work on a list:

```
> take 3 [1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3]
> take 3 "abcde"
"abc"
```

They act on the start of the string, so if you want a general substring function, you need to first `drop` the beginning part of the string you don't want, and then `take` the substring you *do* want.  For example, to get `"bc"` out of `"abcde"`, you want to drop `"a"`:

```
> drop 1 "abcde"
"bcde"
```

and then take `"bc"`:

```
> take 2 (drop 1 "abcde")
"bc"
```

The rest is just math -- the first number "2" should -- in general -- be the length of the desired substring.  The second number "1" should -- in general -- be the starting position (offset zero).

So, try filling in the "???" below with expressions involving `m` and `n`, and if you're still stuck, post an edit or a follow-up question:

```
substr :: Int -> Int -> String -> String
substr m n str = take ??? (drop ??? str)
```

Comment: Thanks for your information.
I think ```take (n-m) (drop m str)``` but, error occurs. Variable not in scope: substr :: [Char] -> Integer -> Integer -> t

Comment: My two-line example above was meant to go in a "xxx.hs" file and be loaded.  It sounds like you tried to enter it at the GHCi interactive prompt.  If so, the first line will give that error.  This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362445/defining-function-signature-in-ghci.

Comment: Can I ask one more? How can I check the bounds? for example, if the length of str is 15, then ( n > m ) && ( 0 < m, n < 15 ) will must be true

Comment: @CPUU No, you can't. New question is a new post.