# What is the multiple line in Haskell ? an operator , a function , something else?

Tags: haskell

I am very new to Haskell , and I must say I am puzzled

I am using GHCi prelude

First attemps to create a factorial

```
Prelude> factorial 0 = 1
Prelude> factorial n = n*factorial(n-1)
Prelude> factorial 2
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

ends up in stack overflow. Obviously recursion has not stopped.

```
Prelude> :t factorial
factorial :: Num t => t -> t
```

Then reading this post [How to define a function in ghci across multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines)

I found out that I have to use either multiple line edition or braces  (by the way is this an operator ?)

```
Prelude> let { fact 0 = 1 ; fact n = n * fact (n-1) }
Prelude> fact 5
120
Prelude> ::t fact
fact :: (Eq p, Num p) => p -> p
```

or

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| facto 0 = 1
Prelude| facto n = n*facto(n-1)
Prelude| :}
Prelude> facto 4
24
Prelude> :t facto
facto :: (Eq p, Num p) => p -> p
```

So, my question is , why the first one is wrong, what happen in this case, why the 2nd and the 3rd are working, and from the result of the :t function, they seem to at least result in the exact same definition.

Comment: No it is just syntax.

Comment: `:{` and `:}` are not even syntax. they are GHCi's commands.

Comment: I find it much more convenient to edit a text file and then (re)load it in ghci. No need for all of these brackets and no surprises such as this one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> why the first one is wrong, what happen in this case

Because you defined **two functions** that had the same name.

First you define:

```
factorial 0 = 1
```

later you define:

```
factorial n = n*factorial(n-1)
```

But Haskell will see the second factorial as a variable that is scoped more local, so the second function definition, *hides* the previous one. The first line (`factorial 0 = 1`) is thus no longer part of the definition. Thus Haskell will evaluate `factorial 2 -> 2 * factorial 1 -> 2 * 1 * factorial 0 -> 2 * 1 * 0 * factorial (-1) -> ...`.

> why the 2nd and the 3rd are working

Because here you define a *single* function, and Haskell interpretets the two clauses as two clauses of the *same* function. The fact that with `:t function` you obtain the same, is just coincidence.

Note that the above only is valid for GHCi. If you work with a `ghc` compiler, it will of course see all your statements as part of the same function definition. In case you mix the clauses of two functions (e.g. first `a 0 = 0`, then `b 0 = 0`, and then `a n = n`) it will error about *multiple definitions for the same function).

Comment: It may be unclear to newer haskell users that this only applies to GHCi, and not compiled programs.

Answer (score 4):

In earlier versions of `ghci`, lines defining functions would have to be prepended with `let`. As of a recent version, the `let` is implicit in any definition line.
What this means is, each line defining your function is treated as its own `let` expression, so each subsequent line replaces (or 'shadows') the previous definition, instead of adding to it as would occur in a regular Haskell program.

The `:{` and `:}` in `ghci` allow you to write several lines as a single input, whereas usually each line is treated independently in `ghci`. This means that you can write a multiline `let` expression:

```
:{
let fact 0 = 1
    fact n = n * fact (n - 1)
:}
```

Or, in later versions, this is equivalent:

```
:{
fact 0 = 1
fact n = n * fact (n - 1)
:}
```

And the function `fact` will be defined as one would expect in a regular Haskell program.

Comment: Yes, GHCi used to require definitions to start their line with `let`. Since GHC-8, this can be omitted though. Questions like this make me wonder whether that was really a good decision...

Comment: About `:{ :}`: it is not Haskell syntax, it is GHCi-only syntax allowing multiline input.

Comment: `:{` and `:}` are independent of whether or not your version of GHCi requires an explicit `let` keyword; they allow you to span a command across multiple physical lines.

Answer (score 1):

When you define

```
Prelude> factorial 0 = 1
Prelude> factorial n = n*factorial(n-1)
Prelude> factorial 2
*** Exception: stack overflow
```

The first definition of `factorial` is discarded, so the function is defined as

```
Prelude> factorial n = n*factorial(n-1)
```

So you don't have a statement to end the recursion anymore.