# redefine function in haskell

Tags: haskell

[image: Is this right or bug?]

I read this article.

> This is a very simple example of a common pattern you will see throughout Haskell. Making basic functions that are obviously correct and then combining them into more complex functions. This way you also avoid repetition. What if some mathematicians figured out that 2 is actually 3 and you had to change your program? You could just redefine `doubleMe` to be `x + x + x` and since `doubleUs` calls `doubleMe`, it would automatically work in this strange new world where 2 is 3.

When I called `doubleUs 3 4` it should return `21` because I redefined the `doubleMe` function, but the function returned `14`.

Comment: Well in ghci, you basically each time write `let` in front of this, and thus redefine the function at every line. If you want to define a multi-line function, you need the following approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846050/how-to-define-a-function-in-ghci-across-multiple-lines

Comment: So yes, the definition still points to the *old* version of `doubleMe`. You can see an identifier as a way to *refer* to some object.

Comment: Please do not add code (or error messages, etc.) to your posts as screenshots -- paste them as text instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article isn't talking about having two definitions of the same function in a program where the latter overrides the former. It's talking about going into your Haskell file and replacing the old definition with the new one.

Generally you can't define two functions with same name in the same scope at all. Your code compiled in GHCi because each definition you enter into GHCi is seen as its own `let` statement, so it starts a new scope. So `doubleUs` used the old definition of `doubleMe` because the new one is in a different scope that `doubleUs` doesn't have access to (and Haskell is lexically scoped, so definitions from inner scopes don't affect functions from the outer scope). If you entered that code into a Haskell file and tried to compile it with GHC, you'd get a warning about an unreachable case because both definitions of `doubleMe` would be seen as a single definition with two patterns that overlap.

Answer (score 1):

you have to execute again `doubleUs x y = doubleMe x + doubleMe y`.